# Having a div fluid horizontal but fixed vertical

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to have a div stay inside the normal document flow horizontally, but have a fixed position vertically?

The idea is to create a div that slides up and down as the user scrolls. But, the div is to maintain
its position horizontally in the case that the user changes the window size.

The best I've been able to do is:

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    left: 70%;
    top: 50px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

This sort of works, but the element starts to wander horizontally when the window is resized (the repositioning offered by the percentage value doesn't ever quite match how I'd like it to).

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: What is the position of the div horizontally?  Is it centered, left align, right align, or something else?  Does the div have to have a fluid width, if so what is that width?  100%?  50%?  Or is it a fixed width?

Need to know all parameters and what the end goal positioning should be.

Comment: It's very hard to imagine exactly how you envision this. When the window is resized, it continues to follow your rules of positioning it 70% of the viewport from the left, and 50px from the top. Maybe you'd be better off using a px or em value for `left`?